# IntelliJ : Bad displaying of equal and minus sign

Tags: java, intellij-idea, editor

I have trouble with these two characters. Text in notepad is idenctical with text in IntelliJ. If anyone know how to solve this problem ?

[image: Screenshot of test program displayed in IntelliJ and notepad]

Comment: I'll pretend to be the funny one - lots of dead pixels? not

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a compatibility issue between Java and the font IntelliJ IDEA uses for text rendering. Please try choosing a different font in Settings | Editor | Colors & Fonts.

Comment: FYI - The [DejaVu Mono](http://dejavu-fonts.org/wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page) font is a nice coding font. It covers a large number of scripts in Unicode and it has good distinction between similar looking characters things like zero vs the letter O and the number one and lowercase L.